# Limits substitution

Tags: real-analysis

Can I use the substitution $x\rightarrow -x$ when $x\rightarrow -\infty$?
I was trying to solve a limit and the solution was to go for this substitution. My question is if I can do this all the time. Thx!
Edit: the function is $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-x$ and I need to know the equation of the oblique asymptote to $-\infty$.

Comment: Do you mean that instead of looking at $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 +x +1}$, you're looking at $f(-x) = \sqrt{x^2 -x +1}$?

Comment: Yes, and that way my limit will become a little bit easier, when $x\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: Well, if you're searching for $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$, I guess it's the same as $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(-x)$ ....

Comment: So at least I cannot think of any reason why not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the substitution as follows:

$f(x)= \sqrt{x^2+x+1}-x =\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-x)(\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x)}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}+1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x}$

You could now use a substitution $x=-t$ then $x \to -\infty$  then $t \to \infty$

$\lim\limits_{t \to +\infty}f(x)=\lim\limits_{t \to +\infty}\left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{t^2}}+1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2-t+1}+x} \right )=1$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your observation is correct. It directly follows from the definition of limit.

Suppose $$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(-x) = L \in \mathbb{R}$$
Then by definition, for all $\varepsilon > 0$ we can find $M > 0$ s.t. for all $x > M$ we have $|f(-x) - L| < \varepsilon$

Next, we want to show $$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = L$$

---

Fix $\epsilon > 0$, we can find $M > 0$ s.t. for all $x > M$ we have $|f(-x) - L| < \varepsilon$

For this $M$, for all $y < -M$, we have $-y > M$, which implies $|f(y) - L| < \varepsilon$ by last sentence.

Note this is exactly the definition of $$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = L$$
So we are done.